# Can I emulate an image manipulation using a neural network?

Tags: neural-network

I have an image represented as a two-dimensional array of floats. I have a function that I apply to this image, which gives me back a new image also represented as a two-dimensional array of floats. This function is time consuming to run, so I am wondering if I can emulate it using a neural network. My initial thought is to use a set of random images, run the function on these and use the outputs to train a neural network that has an input node for each pixel and an output node for each pixel. The images are always 200 * 200 pixels. Does this sound like something that can be done with a neural network? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: depends on your function, could you post it? so we might give it a try using a simulator

Comment: It's actually for an ecological model. Each pixel represents an area of habitat, and starts out with a value of either z = 0 or z = 1. For each pixel where z = 1, I take a bivariate probability distribution centred on the current pixel, and then for every other pixel, I calculate the probability that drawing from this distribution would give me a coordinate pair corresponding to that pixel, i.e I integrate over the area represented by the pixel. Now I can perform the integration ahead of time and shuffle around an array when I visit each pixel with z = 1, but it's still quite expensive.

Comment: The bivariate distribution that I use is a joint uniform, half-cauchy distribution, but you could just use a two-dimensional uniform distribution for testing purposes.